# Hibernate envers does not recognize custom types from hibernate-types-52

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers, hibernate-types

Hibernate envers not able to recognize custom types created using @TypeDef annotations from [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) library.

Audit table generated for MyEntity is using varchar type for status field (enum status type in entity table). After adding "strings" field to entity, I'm getting following exception:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: string-array, at table: _aud, for columns ...

```
@Entity
@Audited
@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType::class),
    TypeDef(name = "string_array", typeClass = StringArrayType::class)
)    
class MyEntity {

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(columnDefinition = "status")
@Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
var status: Status? = null

@Type(type = "string_array")
private var strings: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

}
```

I've already tried to define @TypeDefs on package level using package-info.java file, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "string_array" to "string-array" in your @Type and @TypeDef.

I ran into this problem when I was trying to use JsonBinaryType and I was getting the same kind of exception. I had the name in the @TypeDef set to "json", but for whatever reason Envers was looking for one named "jsonb". In your case, Envers is looking for a type named "string-array".